# Show / Hide Panel with 1 imagebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel, visibility, show

I'm new to asp.net and C#. Right now, I'm creating a small webpage with panels etc.

**Situation:**
I got a Panel (let's say Panel1). And an `Imagebutton` (Button1).
I can Show the Panel (`onclick` event) in aspx with visible = true.

**Problem:**
How do I close the Panel using the same button? I dont want to use Javascipt or jquery or anything else that is Client site.

Is there a simple solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive my ignorance if this isn't available in ASP.NET but could you not do something like

```
Button1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Panel1.Visible = !Panel1.Visible; //toggles visibility
}
```

Comment: That´s it :D worked perfeclty thank you very much :)